# ASP.NET File Path

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ssi

I'm switching a website over from SSI to ASP.NET. The old file structure is like:

root
--pageName
------index.hmtl
------local.css
------local.js

If I have a view (in it's own folder) what file path would I need to use to always reference local files like that? It seems that `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="local.css" />` does not work.

I'm using:
Visual Studio 2010
Framework 4
MVC3

Thanks for the responses.

Clarification:
In this case, most pages have a local.css/local.js, so moving them all to the same directory isn't an ideal solution. I guess the idea was that the link can always be `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="local.css" />` because the file will always have the same name, but it will always be in a separate folder from the other instances of local.css/local.js

Ideally, I could link once, but each page could have it's own personal css/js.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/local.css") %>" />
```

`~` in ASP.NET means the root of the site.

Interestingly, you can also do this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/local.css" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your css files to `~/Content` and change your link to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/local.css")" />
```

ASP.NET MVC uses routes to define paths for your controller actions. The Content path doesn't have routes defined, so it will use the file path instead.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of ASP.Net MVC the path should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
      href="@Url.Content("~/content/css/local.css")" />
```

Hope this will help !!